# Scrape all images from Pinterest board

Tags: dom, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I'm using HTMLAgility pack to scrape all of the images from one of my Pinterest boards. My code only returns 25 results when there should many more items. How can I scrape all image tags from the board?

**Use the Browser Control to load the DOM so we can wait for it before scraping:**

```
    private void LoadHtmlWithBrowser(String url, string dir)
    {
        webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        webBrowser1.Navigate(url);

        waitTillLoad(this.webBrowser1);

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        var documentAsIHtmlDocument3 = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument3)webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(documentAsIHtmlDocument3.documentElement.outerHTML);
        doc.Load(sr);

        Scraper.ScrapeBoard(doc, dir);
    }
```

**Pass in the DOM to this function which iterates through all the image tags**

```
    public static bool ScrapeBoard(HtmlDocument document, string dir)
    {
        //var document = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);
        var urls = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
                                        .Select(e => e.GetAttributeValue("src", null))
                                        .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s));

        //string dir = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().Replace("/", "_") + url.Replace("https://www.", "_");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);

        string localFilename = "";
        foreach (string s in urls)
        {
            try
            {
                localFilename = dir + "/" + Path.GetFileName(s);
                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                    client.DownloadFile(s, localFilename);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

**Function to ensure the entire page is loaded before proceeding**

```
    private void waitTillLoad(WebBrowser webBrControl)
    {
        WebBrowserReadyState loadStatus;
        int waittime = 100000;
        int counter = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            loadStatus = webBrControl.ReadyState;
            Application.DoEvents();
            if ((counter > waittime) || (loadStatus == WebBrowserReadyState.Uninitialized) || (loadStatus == WebBrowserReadyState.Loading) || (loadStatus == WebBrowserReadyState.Interactive))
            {
                break;
            }
            counter++;
        }

        counter = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            loadStatus = webBrControl.ReadyState;
            Application.DoEvents();
            if (loadStatus == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete && webBrControl.IsBusy != true)
            {
                break;
            }
            counter++;
        }
    }
```

When I examine the returned DOM (Stringreader sr), it only shows 25 image tags. Why aren't the rest being extracted or loaded using the technique above?

Answer (score 0):

In order for the page to load fully you have to log into your pinterest account. Also for most boards you have to scroll down as it loads more pictures.